# After the statement "a - 1" in while loop the variable ''a'' doesn't change its value

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JavaScript and don't understand why the statement "a - 1" in while loop doesn't work

```
var a = 5;

while(a > 0) {
 console.log(a);
 a - 1;
}
```

Comment: `a - 1` will not change the value of the variable. I think you may have been thinking of `a -= 1`

Comment: @John , use a = a-1 to get expected result , currently "a" value remains same as it is not assigned back to a  or use a--

Comment: Hi John. Welcome to SO. Your question is very likely to have bad feedback on this website as the SO community is not keen on solving basic problems that you should learn to solve elsewhere before posting them here. Yours is indeed a very basic issue and doesn't contribute to the StackOverflow content as it's not a learning website. You should consider removing your question and posting elsewhere. You're still welcome of course and I encourage you to come back here and post when you'll have mastered the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned the result to your variable.

```
a - 1;
4;         // This is equivalent to the first line.
a = a - 1; // This works, but is tedious to write
a -= 1;    // This works too! but there must be a better way.
a--;       // Shorthand
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign result of operation `a-1` to `a` variable. Otherwise for each iteration `a` will stay with value `5`. So your loop will never end.

```
var a = 5;

while(a > 0) {
 console.log(a);
 a = a - 1; // or a -= 1; for short
}
```